# Firebase Cloud Messaging background notification channel ID not being set in Android O

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-8.0-oreo

Firebase doesn't seem to be setting the Notification channelId on incoming messages to android M. I'm following [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message?authuser=0), and trying to get notifications to fire when my app is in the background.

Here's my app code and manifest.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private void registerNotificationChannel(String id, String name, String description) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        mChannel.enableVibration(true);
        mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    //private BroadcastReceiver isms;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG,"MainActivity.oncreate. token is:" +  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        registerNotificationChannel("default","default","all other notifications");
        registerNotificationChannel("channel1","channel1","notification channel 1");
        registerNotificationChannel("channel2","channel2","notification channel 2");
    }

    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebase message received");
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : data.entrySet())
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "data: " + entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

    }
}

    public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed firebase " +
                "" +
                "" +
                "token: " + refreshedToken);
    }
}

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.phauna.alerter">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="default"/>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

As you can see, I'm definitely registering my notification channels as it says [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels). This screenshot from my device confirms the channels are registered as well:

[image]

Here's the critical part. **When I target API version 25, I get background notifications. As soon as I target version 26, I do not.** Instead,
I get this error message in logcat:

```
10-11 12:40:00.925   899  8910 E NotificationService: No Channel found for pkg=org.phauna.alerter, channelId=null, id=0, tag=GCM-Notification:286245598, opPkg=org.phauna.alerter, callingUid=10179, userId=0, incomingUserId=0, notificationUid=10179, notification=Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=content://settings/system/notification_sound defaults=0x0 flags=0x10 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
```

I'm definitely setting a channel ID, as depicted in this screenshot sending from the Firebase console:

[image]

I have also tried sending through the HTTP service:

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<redacted>" --Header "Content-Type: application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{\"to\":\"<redacted>\",\"data\":{\"android_channel_id\":\"channel1\"},\"notification\":{\"body\":\"this is a testfoobar\"}}"
```

In both cases, the message reaches my device but does not have a channelId (as indicated by channelId=null in the above log message).

In the foreground, I can catch the notification with the service and manually stick a channel ID on it (even if I have to encode the channel ID in the payload of the message). But I need the background notifications to work as well, and as far as I know, that's up to the Firebase library to get right.

Comment: What version of `firebase-messaging` are you building with?  In a test app of mine built with 11.4.2, when a notification with unregistered channel ID is received, I see the notification and this log message: `W/FirebaseMessaging: Notification Channel requested (channel_X) has not been created by the app. Manifest configuration, or default, value will be used.`

Comment: Hmm, that could be the issue. I just used the firebase assistant to install the firebase-messaging package and it automatically picked 10.0.1. Let me get it updated and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) indicate that support for notification channels was added in version 10.2.6 (May 17, 2017):

> Added support for Android O notification channels. Android clients can
>   specify a default notification channel in the application manifest
>   which will be used if the downstream message does not contain a
>   notification_channel parameter.

Update your build to use version 10.2.6 or later.

Comment: I updated to 11.4.2 and my problem is fixed! Thanks Bob!

Comment: I am unable to find *android_channel_id** @Bob do you know where it is.

Comment: @MaheshGawhane: Not sure what you mean.  Maybe the default channel [described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest).

Comment: @Bob in **AndroidManifest** there is **metadata** for **notication_channel_id**. Inside this metadata there is value **@string/default_notification_channel_id**. so my question is what data i have to put in **default_notification_channel_id** string.

Comment: For anyone still wondering about what to put in the default_notification_channel_id: the name speaks for itself, you place whatever you want your default channel id to be here, e.g. 1. This channel id will be used when the notification does not specify a channel id.